# Generate random numbers into a table

Tags: javascript, html, random, generator

I am trying to generate random numbers as well as the current minute into a table.
How do I have the script write into the table?
`getElementbyClass()`?

```
d = new Date();
var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*60)
document.writeln(random);

var Minutes = d.getMinutes();
document.writeln(Minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var d = new Date();
var random= Math.floor(Math.random()*60);
var td1 = document.createElement("td");
td1.innerHTML = random;

var Minutes = d.getMinutes();
var td2 = document.createElement("td");
td2.innerHTML = random;

var table = document.getElementById("tblResult");
var row = document.createElement("tr");

row.appendChild(td1);
row.appendChild(td2);
table.appendChild(row);
```

And int the HTML:

```
<table id="tblResult">
  <tr>
    <td>Random</td>
    <td>Minutes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Result can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMWjn/)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a set number of rows/column in the table? Do you need to update the table in run-time (e.g. will you change the contents in the columns after the page has been loaded)?

If you just want to create a table with those values when loading the page, you could create your table in JavaScript:

```
var table = document.createElement('table'),
    row,
    minCol,
    ranCol;

function addRow(minutes, rand) {
    row = document.createElement('tr');
    minCol = document.createElement('td');
    ranCol = document.createElement('td');

    minCol.innerHTML = minutes;
    ranCol.innerHTML = rand;

    row.appendChild(minCol);
    row.appendChild(ranCol);
    table.appendChild(row);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    addRow((new Date()).getMinutes(), Math.floor(Math.random() * 60));
}

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Note that this script must be *after* the `<body>` tag for it to work.

If you need to add rows after the page has loaded (e.g. the user clicks a button) just call `addRow()`.